# .append .prepend issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, append, prepend

Hi I'm having an issue on using .append .prepend method of JQuery I know these methods very well but there is a weird glitch happening when I tried such a code:

```
$("#nashgraphics-menu ul li a.toplevel-a")
 .prepend('<span class="main-navigation-button-left"></span><span class="main-navigation-button-body"><h1>');
$("#nashgraphics-menu ul li a.toplevel-a")
 .append('</h1></span><span class="main-navigation-dropdown-button-right"></span>');
```

it should work properly but unfortunately it didn't and I'm wondering why

**Note: I'm Talking about the "Link" text, those tags should wrap that text but it doesn't**

the code should output this one:

```
<span class="main-navigation-button-left"></span>
<span class="main-navigation-button-body"><h1>Link</h1></span>
<span class="main-navigation-dropdown-button-right"></span>
```

but it goes like this:

```
<span class="main-navigation-button-left"></span>
<span class="main-navigation-button-body"><h1></h1></span>Link<span class="main-navigation-dropdown-button-right"></span>
```

**that text "Link" should be inside the  tag**

**Here's the whole code I'm using this for Wordpress by the way**

```
;(function($){
$.fn.nashgraphics_menu = function(){
    $("#nashgraphics-menu ul li").each(function(index){
        $('#nashgraphics-menu ul li').addClass('toplevel-nochild');
        $('#nashgraphics-menu ul li ul li').removeClass('toplevel-nochild').addClass('nochild');
        $('#nashgraphics-menu ul li:has(ul)').removeClass('toplevel-nochild nochild').addClass('toplevel');
        $('#nashgraphics-menu ul li ul li:has(ul)').removeClass('toplevel nochild').addClass('haschild');

        $('#nashgraphics-menu ul li a').addClass('toplevel-nochild-a');
        $('#nashgraphics-menu ul li ul li a').removeClass('toplevel-nochild-a').addClass('nochild-a');
        $('#nashgraphics-menu ul li:has(ul) > a').removeClass('toplevel-nochild-a nochild-a').addClass('toplevel-a');
        $('#nashgraphics-menu ul li ul li:has(ul) > a').removeClass('toplevel-a nochild-a').addClass('haschild-a');
    });

    $("#nashgraphics-menu ul li a.toplevel-a").prepend('<span class="main-navigation-button-left"></span><span class="main-navigation-button-body"><h1>');
    $("#nashgraphics-menu ul li a.toplevel-a").append('</h1></span><span class="main-navigation-dropdown-button-right"></span>');

    $('#nashgraphics-menu ul li a.haschild-a').append('&nbsp; &raquo;');
};
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: You are misusing prepend and append method, see DOC. BTW, jquery API get a .wrap() method.

Comment: Yes but I also tried this one, this is a good Idea too but I can't find a solution for this .wrap() too work on my code unless I know how to select the text inside the <a> tag and wrap it I've tried this one but didn't worked $("#nashgraphics-menu ul li a.toplevel-a").text().wrap('content content');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking in terms of *markup*, but you're not dealing with markup by the time you're modifying the page, you're dealing with DOM objects.

If your goal is to put each `#nashgraphics-menu ul li a.toplevel-a` element inside the structure you've described, use the [`wrap` function](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$("#nashgraphics-menu ul li a.toplevel-a").wrap('<span class="main-navigation-button-left"></span><span class="main-navigation-button-body"><h1></h1></span><span class="main-navigation-dropdown-button-right"></span>');
```

...although I'm not 100% certain that `wrap` can handle a complex structure like that. You may have to create the structure separately, like this:

```
$("#nashgraphics-menu ul li a.toplevel-a").each(function() {
    var $a = $(this),
        $wrapper;

    // Create the wrapper
    $wrapper = $('<span class="main-navigation-button-left"></span><span class="main-navigation-button-body"><h1></h1></span><span class="main-navigation-dropdown-button-right"></span>');

    // Insert it prior to the anchor
    $wrapper.insertBefore($a);

    // Move the anchor into the `h1`
    $wrapper.find('h1').append($a);
});
```

---

Just for reference, to give a less complicated example of `wrap`, this:

```
$(".foo").wrap('<div class="bar"></div>');
```

...puts a `div` with class `"bar"` around every element with class `"foo"`.

---

Re your comment:

> Yes I had also thought about that but my concern is I want to wrap the text inside the  tag and not the  tag itself

Okay, so that's slightly different:

```
$("#nashgraphics-menu ul li a.toplevel-a").each(function() {
    var $a = $(this);

    $a.html('<span class="main-navigation-button-left"></span><span class="main-navigation-button-body"><h1>' + $a.html() + '</h1></span><span class="main-navigation-dropdown-button-right"></span>');
});
```

Comment: you could also use $.replaceWith(), something along these lines: `$('a').replaceWith('<div>blah'+$('a').html()+'</div>');` since we're dealing with such complex HTML. seems alot of buggering around to change some markup, I wonder why it's needed?

Comment: Yes I had also thought about that but my concern is I want to wrap the text inside the <a> tag and not the <a> tag itself

Comment: I'm using JQuery on wordpress by the way so It automatically generates the lists and the <a> tags so I just need to append and prepend those

Comment: This is really a nice explanation as usual T.J.

Comment: @NazareneGonzales: I've added a bit at the end about how you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the browser or jQuery add the closing tag to make a valid HTML because since the `prepend` is executed it won't be valid until `append` be executed.

Take a look at [`wrap` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.